# how to ping between hosts under 2 switches,which dont have a switch-switch link? pox controller

Tags: sdn, pox

how to ping between hosts under 2 switches,which have no link switch-switch connection??
switch1(connect to host1) and switch2(connect to host2) are connected to the controller,...Is it possible to ping between host1 and host2?

c1
  /\
s1  s2
/    \
h1    h2

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible and the controller will not be able to find a route between the two hosts.